# php-fpm docker container not reachable in Google App Engine

Tags: php, docker, symfony, google-app-engine, dockerfile

I am trying to move my Symfony application to the Google Cloud. For this I need 2 containers, one nginx and one php-fpm. Currently I develop locally with compose and run it in a compute instance via compose. Now I want to switch to a more scalable (and CI applicable) approach.

My Problem is that the docker image I use does not work in the App Engine (in Cloud Run it does not work either). Ready & Health Check are failing, and even without the checks I cannot connect to the service (e.g. a locally running nginx with upstream set to the App Engine). Locally everything works fine.

My workflow is simply build this image, and push it to the app engine via
`gcloud app deploy --image-url eu.gcr.io/digital-index-ws1920/php-fpm-prod:0.15`

edit: app yaml is

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

When I connect to the app engine via browser, I see a 502, with local nginx it times out.

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.11

RUN sed -i 's/9000/${PORT}/' /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf

COPY .docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini

RUN apk --update --no-cache add git
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
WORKDIR /var/www
COPY app /var/www
RUN mkdir http-cache && chown www-data:www-data http-cache/
RUN composer update; composer; composer dump-autoload --no-interaction
CMD php-fpm
EXPOSE ${PORT}
```

Comment: There should be some additional info in the logs for the service. Also check Cloud Build logs as it is used for deployment. Also check if [default resources](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings) are enough for your app and increase them if needed.

Comment: If you are eligible for technical support I would suggest opening a ticket for investigation. Otherwise we need something to start from, maybe you could trim your code and give us a simple reproducible example?

Comment: For testing I created a basic php docker image. The same issue is there. You can find it (https://gitlab.com/patriksimms/gcp-test)

Can the issue have smth todo with the location of the start script? This would explain why it does not work by default with the app engine by default. But why it does not work with a locally running nginx with my config which works with compose? You can find the nginx dockerfile and the config also in gitlab

Comment: I can't really reproduce it with this files, i am not much into php, can you please edit the question and add step-by-step reproduction to it? Also please edit nginx conf file at gitlab as it has information on your project.

Comment: After a long time of try- and- error i found out, that it has something to to with the php-fpm process itself. @E

Comment: @psimms did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @Eric No, I gave up and deployed the nginx and the php-fpm as docker containers each in their own Google Compute Engine running on container optimized OS