# Google App Engine - 502 error with custom docker image

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, craftcms, google-app-engine-php

I cannot seem to get my Craft CMS container to run in Google App Engine. I am building the image locally with a custom Dockerfile and pushing the image out to my project container registry.

The deploy goes fine, the /nginx_health checks show as a 200 in the logs, but every time I navigate to the page in the browser I see a 502 with the following error message in the GAE browser console:

```
[error] 34#34: *320 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 2607:f8b0:4007:818::2014, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.1:8080/", host: "craft-cms.uw.r.appspot.com"
```

I am exposing port 8080 in the Dockerfile.

Here is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

runtime_config:
    document_root: craftcms/web

vm_health_check:
 enable_health_check: False

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

My nginx-app.conf file:

```
location / {
  # try to serve file directly, fallback to front controller
  try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Not sure if this matters, but this is how I'm closing out the Dockerfile:

```
RUN /scripts/run.sh

COPY ./config-env/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
COPY ./config-env/php-fpm.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n"]
```

run.sh does some busy work for Craft, the config files are copied over and then I explicitly call supervisord.

All I see in the browser is the 502/nginx page. Thoughts on other things I can try?

Comment: Hi @Eric, can you check if your App Engine application has run out of memory. Follow the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-response-errors#error_message_bad_gateway).

Comment: @JMGelilio I'm not seeing the out of memory error in the logs

Comment: Thanks @Eric. In GAE Flex, 502 error can be caused by a number of reasons. The common cause is if the app(container) fails to contact on port 8080 but if you think that your configure is correct for this case try upgrade your resources and/or instance in `app.yaml`. If you are eligible for technical support I would suggest opening a ticket for futher investigation. Also your case is some similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61305752/8753991)